# Wand or 2 foot long stick between my master bath fan and outdoor flood lights connecting to share wiring for power?

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac

I'm divorced. My ex husband had a guy install a junction box on corner of house to spotlight the swing set years ago. Recently I was in the attic and discoved a 2 ft "stick' or "wand' that was quite heavy or hard to move as it was bending the slanted cardboard ----that keeps the dust and rain from entering the attic -----flat down and not as it is supposed to be. It is linking the wiring from the fan (master bath shower is in back corner of house so it's the closet electrical connectionto share power with spotlight junction box? I assume- altho it's labeled to b on it's own gfi) to the spotlight with wiring exiting the attic under the roof overhang openings that access outside....and to spotlight addition. So in short u have the exaust fan for master bath shower --viewing  in and from attic.....wiring extended to some 2 foot stick or wand' attactched at one end and with snake looking fangs curling downward at other end....same wiring picking back up there and going out screen holes under roof overhang to junction box housing two- 60 w large outdoor bulbs with an pipe covering wires...running down house to the switch. Ends. Nothing past the light switch. What is this wand!? They are not variable speed or to give lighting options..... one speed fan only and one option light brightness so not dimmer or switcher. Data stick? He loves all things smart home or remotely controllable by plane train or automobile while he travels  in states or internationally. Also can't get him off our phones altho we have no wifi cable or otherwise anymore and no modems to speak of.  We do have  garage door genie, pool intelleclor capable and smart thermostats that have minds of their own and programmable scheduls we can't gain control if. Maybe not related but FYI. That's all i got. Help anyone. Sorry so long but desperatly seeking knowledge and control of home. He won't help or answer. Also no motion control. Plain on off outdoor light.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange. The description is difficult to follow. Photos are going to be needed in order to get any kind of answers.

Comment: Can you post photos of this? It sounds like a conduit of some sort, but we can't tell what's going on from your description

Comment: I agree it sounds like a stick of conduit, but cardboard being used to keep rain out??? We really need photos here.